# unable to remove factors in tmap data

Tags: r, tidyverse, tmap, forcats

I'm starting to get acquainted with using R in mapping and I am currently working with the `tmap` package. I am running into problems when subsetting the data. I can select various subsets using the tidyverse syntax without problems, but I am unable to remove the unused levels to ensure that the legends remain reasonable.

```r
#// load library and data
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)
data("World")

#// subset data to only include Africa
tm_africa <- filter(World, continent == "Africa") 
tm_shape(tm_africa) + tm_polygons("name")
#> Warning: Number of levels of the variable "name" is 177, which is
#> larger than max.categories (which is 30), so levels are combined. Set
#> tmap_options(max.categories = 177) in the layer function to show all levels.
#> Some legend labels were too wide. These labels have been resized to 0.62, 0.45, 0.54, 0.59, 0.50, 0.62, 0.61, 0.62, 0.47, 0.46, 0.63. Increase legend.width (argument of tm_layout) to make the legend wider and therefore the labels larger.
```

[image]

```r
#// remove unused levels for proper legends
#// output suggests levels are indeed dropped
forcats::fct_drop(tm_africa$name)
#>  [1] Angola               Burundi              Benin               
#>  [4] Burkina Faso         Botswana             Central African Rep.
#>  [7] Cote d'Ivoire        Cameroon             Dem. Rep. Congo     
#> [10] Congo                Djibouti             Algeria             
#> [13] Egypt                Eritrea              Ethiopia            
#> [16] Gabon                Ghana                Guinea              
#> [19] Gambia               Guinea-Bissau        Eq. Guinea          
#> [22] Kenya                Liberia              Libya               
#> [25] Lesotho              Morocco              Madagascar          
#> [28] Mali                 Mozambique           Mauritania          
#> [31] Malawi               Namibia              Niger               
#> [34] Nigeria              Rwanda               W. Sahara           
#> [37] Sudan                S. Sudan             Senegal             
#> [40] Sierra Leone         Somaliland           Somalia             
#> [43] Swaziland            Chad                 Togo                
#> [46] Tunisia              Tanzania             Uganda              
#> [49] South Africa         Zambia               Zimbabwe            
#> 51 Levels: Algeria Angola Benin Botswana Burkina Faso Burundi ... Zimbabwe

#// check if levels are removed
#// still listing countries from outside Africa
head(levels(tm_africa$name))
#> [1] "Afghanistan" "Albania"     "Algeria"     "Angola"      "Antarctica" 
#> [6] "Argentina"

#// plot again to verify levels have not changed
tm_shape(tm_africa) + tm_polygons("name")
#> Warning: Number of levels of the variable "name" is 177, which is
#> larger than max.categories (which is 30), so levels are combined. Set
#> tmap_options(max.categories = 177) in the layer function to show all levels.
#> Some legend labels were too wide. These labels have been resized to 0.62, 0.45, 0.54, 0.59, 0.50, 0.62, 0.61, 0.62, 0.47, 0.46, 0.63. Increase legend.width (argument of tm_layout) to make the legend wider and therefore the labels larger.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You need to reassign the modified vector into the data with `tm_africa$name <- fct_drop(tm_africa$name)`

Comment: Ugh. I am an idiot! Now I'm not sure if I should leave the question up as a testament or remove it to not clutter up SO with stupid questions.

Comment: If you think others might make same silly mistake as you then leave it around. If not the delete it.